# Redux: Distinguish objects in reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I'm quite new to Redux and from what I understand, a reducer should be created for each type of object. E.g. for user interaction a user reducer should be created. **My question is:** How do you handle cases where you require the object for different purposes?

**Scenario:** Imagine having a user reducer which returns the current user. This user would be required in the entire application and needed for general controls on every page.

Now what happens when you need to load another user which is used for different purposes. E.g. profile page: loading a user to display information.

In this case there would be a conflict if the user reducer would be used. What would be the correct way to handle this in Redux? In case a different reducer would have to be created, what would be the naming convention for the new reducer?

Comment: A reducer is to model part of the state tree. So for your user example, you could have a `users` node on the state tree (un-related to page type), and your reducer updates/adds/removes items from that collection. Your smart components can then load that user object (selected from state tree using react-redux `connect`) for different contexts.

Comment: This would work fine once you only use one set of users. What would you do if you have multiple components which load different users sets? What would be the recommended approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you've mentioned:

> a user reducer which loads the current user

I don't know if I got you correctly, but if this means you want to fetch (from an API, for example) the current user inside the reducer, this is a wrong approach.

Reducers are intended to be [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). You can call them with the same arguments multiple times and they will always return the same expected state.

Side effects like that should be handled by [action creators](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html), for example:

**actions/user.js**

```js
export const FETCH_ME = 'FETCH_ME'
export const FETCH_ME_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_ME_SUCCESS' 

// it's using redux-thunk (withExtraArgument: api) module to make an async action creator
export const fetchMe = () => (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_ME })
  return api.get('/users/me').then(({ data }) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_ME_SUCCESS, data })
    return data
  })
}
```

Inside your reducer you can simple get the data and set a new state (note that if you send the action with the same data multiple times, the state will always be the same).

**reducers/user.js**

```js
import { FETCH_ME, FETCH_ME_SUCCESS } from '../actions/user'

const initialState = {
  item: null,
  loading: false
}

export const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ME:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case FETCH_ME_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        item: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Now, for your scenario:

> Now what happens when you need to load another user which is used for different purposes. E.g. profile page: loading a user to display information.

You will just write another action creator for that:

**actions/user.js**

```js
export const FETCH_ME = 'FETCH_ME'
export const FETCH_ME_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_ME_SUCCESS' 
export const FETCH_USER = 'FETCH_USER'
export const FETCH_USER_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS'

export const fetchMe = () => (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_ME })
  return api.get('/users/me').then(({ data }) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_ME_SUCCESS, data })
    return data
  })
}

export const fetchUser = (id) => (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER })
  return api.get(`/users/${id}`).then(({ data }) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER_SUCCESS, data })
    return data
  })
}
```

Then you adapt your reducer to manage more sets:

**reducers/user.js**

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { FETCH_ME, FETCH_ME_SUCCESS, FETCH_USER, FETCH_USER_SUCCESS } from '../actions/user'

const initialState = {
  item: null,
  loading: false
}

const meReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ME:
    case FETCH_ME_SUCCESS:
      return userReducer(state, action)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const activeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
    case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
      return userReducer(state, action)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
    case FETCH_ME:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
    case FETCH_ME_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        item: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  activeUser: activeReducer,
  me: meReducer
})
```

Your final user state should be something like:

```js
{
  me: {
    item: null,
    loading: false
  },
  active: {
    item: null,
    loading: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, I'm loading the user in my action. That was my bad in the initial description. I'll correct it, the reducer example with multiple sets was just what I was looking for, thanks!